# Validate JWT then redirect request

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, jwt, haproxy

My application requires a JWT for access. I would like to set up a web server to sit in front of an HAProxy to perform the validation of the JWT.

For example, a user requests mysite.prod.com. The request is sent to the web server which validates the JWT. I then need the web server to redirect the user's request to the HAProxy for load balancing.

The issue I'm having is being able to redirect the request with the same headers (most specifically the host field) to the HAProxy. I am using PHP header() on the web server to redirect the request but when the HAProxy receives the redirect, the host field is no longer correct (mysite.prod.com) so it does not match any of the rules.

Is there a way to perform my JWT validation then redirect the request, including the same header fields with which it came?

Comment: any specific reason why you need to validate JWT before hitting HAproxy? Normally the Loadbalancer is in front of everything. As example having HAproxy in front and validate if an JWT token exists, either as Cookie or parameter then hitting the webserver to fully validate JWT. Otherwise you can define multiple header() calls within PHP to define them before redirect

Comment: I have posted another question previously about how to do this AT the HAProxy with no successful answers so I decided to try a different approach.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836167/jwt-validation-in-haproxy

I would like for the JWT validation to occur at the HAProxy, then forward to a backend if it is successfully validated.

Comment: (StackOverflow cut me off...) If I send to a backend to validate the JWT I'll have the same issue I'm having here, not forwarding with the same host parameter from the php code.

I have tried adding a host header() value in my php but that sets a response header instead of request

Comment: HAproxy supports LUA, maybe that's an alternative for you